# jeasyui Editable datagrid not firing event onSuccess

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

[editable grid documentation](http://jeasyui.com/extension/edatagrid.php)

[detailview documentation](http://www.jeasyui.com/extension/datagridview.php)

im using a normal datagrid with detailview, and when this expands a row it will get a subdatagrid, this subdatagrid is where the edatagrid is used, i need to be able to edit 1 value from the row, and i am able to do this correctly, but for some reason the on Success event is never triggering. onError is triggering fine though.

Any suggestions into why onSuccess isn't triggered?

here is how im creating the edatagrid.

```
$('#ddv2-'+index).edatagrid({
url:'getOrderDetailProvision.php?id='+row.Id,           
updateUrl: 'update_sim.php',
fitColumns:true,
singleSelect:true,
rownumbers:true,
height:'auto',
autoSave:true,
columns:[[
   {field:'Serie',title:'Serie',width:40},
   {field:'UniqueId',title:'Unique ID', width:40},
   {field:'AVL',title:'AVL ID', width:40},
   {field:'sim',title:'Sim', width:40,editor:'textbox'},
   {field:'Numero',title:'Numero Telefonico',width:40},
   {field:'Producto',title:'Producto',width:40}
]],
    onError: function(index2,row2){
        console.log("onError");
    console.log(row2);
},
onSave: function(index3,row3){
    console.log("onSave");
    console.log(row3);
},
onSuccess:function(index4,row4){
    console.log("onSuccess");
    console.log(row4.msg);
},
onEdit:function(index5,row5){
    console.log("onEdit");
}
});
```

and my updateURL 'update_sim.php'

```
<?php
include "includes/db_config.php";
include "ChromePhp.php";
$post = getRealPOST();
ChromePHP::log("Array : ", $post);
$id = intval($post['Id']);
$Serie = $post['Serie'];
$Producto = $post['Producto'];
$AVL = $post['AVL'];
$UniqueId = $post['UniqueId'];
$sim = $post['sim'];
$conn = sqlsrv_connect(SV_NAME, $connectionInfo) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
$sql = "SELECT Id,Numero from Lineas WHERE Sim= $sim";
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$result = array();  
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);
if(sqlsrv_num_rows($res) == 0){
    echo json_encode(array(
    'isError' => true,
    'msg' => 'No existe SIM en BD'
    ));
    ChromePHP::log("Error no rows");
    ChromePHP::log($sql);
}else if(sqlsrv_num_rows > 1){
    ChromePHP::log("Error no rows");
    echo json_encode(array(
    'isError' => true,
    'msg' => 'Multiples SIM en BD'
    ));
}else{
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    $telefono = $row['Numero'];
    $sql = "UPDATE producto SET Sim_Id=(SELECT Id from Lineas WHERE Sim= $sim) WHERE Id = $id"; 
    $res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);
    echo json_encode(array(
    'isSuccess' => true,
    'Id' => $Id,
    'Serie' => $Serie,
    'UniqueId' => $UniqueId,
    'AVL' => $AVL,
    'Producto' => $Producto,
    'sim' => $sim,
    'Numero' => $telefono
    ));
    ChromePHP::log($sql);
}

function getRealPOST() {
    $pairs = explode("&", file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $vars = array();
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        $nv = explode("=", $pair);
        $name = urldecode($nv[0]);
        $value = urldecode($nv[1]);
        $vars[$name] = $value;
    }
    return $vars;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i had a dump error, because the echoing json array was $Id instead of $id by having a NULL it would not trigger the success event.